# Add-AzureRmVhd : Resource group 'ResourceGroupName' could not be found

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-powershell, rm, vhd

I'm trying to **import VHD** via **PowerShell** in a **Virtual Machine** but am getting errors.

```
Add-AzureRmVhd : Resource group 'ResourceGroupName' could not be found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AzureRmVhd  -ResourceGroupName ResourceGroupName -destination 
"https ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureRmVhd], CloudException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.StorageServices.AddAzureVhdCommand
```

These are the steps I am following:

1. Install-Module AzureRM -AllowClobber
2. Connect-AzureRmAccount
3. `Add-AzureRmVhd  -ResourceGroupName VMWinServerFtH -destination "https://vhdexternal.blob.core.windows.net/oldvhd/test.vhd" -LocalFilePath "C:\Users\administrador\Desktop\disk.vhd"`

[image]

I've already verified the correct spelling of the resource group name.

Comment: Firstly you should be using the `Az` module; as the warning states AzureRM is deprecated and will be retired in less than a year. Secondly, can you run `Get-AzureRMContext` and confirm that you're connected to the correct subscription? Finally, without changing the context, you can run `Get-AzureRMResourceGroup` to list all resource groups and confirm that the name exists as you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note**  that: AzureRM PowerShell modules will be depreacted on 29 February 2024. Refer this  [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/migrate-from-azurerm-to-az?view=azps-10.0.0).

I have download VHD file from disk. To import VHD via PowerShell in a Virtual Machine check the below workaround.

```
Install-Module -Name az.compute -RequiredVersion 5.2.0
Get-Module
```

[image]

Now to import VHD file from local file to storage account you can make use of below commands:

The  [**Add-AzVhd**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/add-azvhd?view=azps-10.0.0)  command uploads an on-premises virtual hard disk to a managed disk or a blob storage account.

```
Add-AzVhd -ResourceGroupName -<YourRGName> -Destination "http://contosoaccount.blob.core.windows.net/vhdstore/win7baseimage.vhd" -LocalFilePath "C:\vhd\WinImage.vhd"
```

[image]

To confirm in portal:

[image]